# additional users on EC2 windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have spun up an EC2 windows instance in AWS. I would like to know how to enable login for the users with ssh key pairs in windows? Is it possible or should I just use windows login (username / password) without any pem keys? I am new to windows.

Comment: On Window's you might have it join an Active Directory domain controller, and have user accounts (username+passwords) on there to allow users to reuse logins, even automatically without prompts. There is also a certificate based system without passwords, but not seen it used so would need to investigate. At any rate nothing specific to Amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSH key is only used for decrypting *Administrator* password on Windows EC2 instances, not for the actual logging in.

In your case simply create local users on your Windows EC2 or join the machine to your Active Directory domain to use shared user accounts. Just like any other Windows machine.

Hope that helps :)